# Phabricator review only specific files

Tags: git, phabricator, arcanist

I want to create some diff's out of some specific files, discarding the git history on them

Is that possible?

Something like

```
arc diff -- file1.{h,cpp} file2.{h,cpp}
```

I know it might sound counter productive, but I have a big batch of code, with commits not necessarily encompassing a single issue/functionality.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: No. I've played with git to create separate commitscin different branches, reviewed them all, and merged back.

Answer (score -2):

You're not required to use arcanist, you can copy/paste any old diff into Differential directly.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question, though.  it seems the issue is that differential wants to review diffs, and the questioner wants to review the content of an entire file en masse.